# Excessive use of let a problem in Clojure?

Tags: haskell, clojure

I have this set of functions - it works, but I'm concerned about the use of `let`s.

```
(defn- create-counts [coll]
  "Computes how many times did each 'next state' come from a 'previous state'.
   The result type is {previous_state {next_state count}}."
  (let [past    coll
        present (rest coll)
        zipped  (map vector past present)
        sorted  (sort zipped)
        grouped (group-by first sorted)
        seconds (map (fn [[key pairs]] [key (map second pairs)]) (seq grouped))
        freqs   (map (fn [[key secs]]  [key (frequencies secs)]) seconds)]
    (into {} freqs)))
```

I started learning functional programming in Haskell some time ago, and there, because of laziness, it's commonplace to use this equivalent of Clojure `let`, because what's not needed, isn't ever computed:

```
asnwer = z
  where
    notused = map (^1000) [1000..10000]
    x = [1..]
    y = take 10 x
    z = map (*2) y
```

- *Is it okay to use Clojure `let` in this way?* Look for example at the `create-counts` fn definition - I use it quite heavily there.
- *Would it be better to just put it all inside one expression?*
- *What's the best practice for this?*

I like how everything's named, but I don't know if there's not a performance penalty hidden somewhere.

When I try to match the Haskell example with Clojure code, it seems there's eager evaluation:

```
(let [notused (do (Thread/sleep (rand 10000000)) :done)
      x       (iterate inc 1)
      y       (take 10 x)
      z       (map #(* 2 %) y)]
  z)

;=> sleeps till the judgement day
```

I could imagine preventing this with futures or some clever let-like macro, but really it seems to me that I'm trying to do something Haskell-y (lazy) in Clojure. What's the idiomatic way?

Comment: Just a note that the Haskell equivalent of the clojure `let` is `let`. `where` is a different beast

Comment: Thanks, jozefg. Links with more info: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html#sect4.5 and http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where

Comment: I'm a clojure noob, but the documentation for map says it returns a lazy sequence.  Group-by is not lazy.  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map

Comment: Your Clojure example sleeps forever because "do" is an eager construct. Not everything is lazy in clojure. Look at the doc, and make sure you are working with lazy functions. I'm not sure what your notused map... code does in Haskell, but you can use map for it in Clojure also, and it'll be lazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you could use abstract structural binding (a.k.a. destructuring) to reduce the number of `let` bindings:

```
(defn- create-counts_org [[_ & present :as coll]]
  "Computes how many times did each 'next state' come from a 'previous state'.
   The result type is {previous_state {next_state count}}."
  (let [zipped  (map vector coll present)
        sorted  (sort zipped)
        grouped (group-by first sorted)
        seconds (map (fn [[key pairs]] [key (map second pairs)]) (seq grouped))
        freqs   (map (fn [[key secs]]  [key (frequencies secs)]) seconds)]
    (into {} freqs)))
```

I think there's nothing wrong in using `let` bindings that are technically not necessary to improve readability and comprehensibility.

But in your function, I think it is pretty clear what every step does:

- `sorted` -> the first thing I see is the `sort` function
- `grouped` ->  the first thing I see is the `group-by` function
- `seconds` / `freqs` -> I think these are also pretty clear, using `second` and `frequencies`

And because each `let` binding just uses the previous binding once, I would probably use the [`thread-last (->>)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro:

```
(defn- create-counts [[_ & rest :as coll]]
  "Computes how many times did each 'next state' come from a 'previous state'.
   The result type is {previous_state {next_state count}}."
  (->>  (map vector coll rest)
        (sort)
        (group-by first)
        (map (fn [[key pairs]] [key (map second pairs)]))
        (map (fn [[key secs]]  [key (frequencies secs)]))
        (into {})))
```

I think this also answers your *better to just put it all inside one expression* question. Also, even if there where a performance penalty in using `let` bindings, it would probably be negligible.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen the ->> macro before, but didn't think about it. Seems handy.